# How can I get stats on my network data usage?

Tags: networking

I noticed recently that my home external-facing router is showing that a lot of data has been downloaded in the last few days. Everything appears to be secured so I don't think it's anything malicious, and there are certainly activities on the network that will cause a lot of data to be pulled down (downloading digital games, for example).

I'd like to get a better understanding of what is using all of the data: either by device or by "service". By service, I mean a breakdown like:
Netflix used 20Gb
Xbox Live used 30Gb
etc

What options are available for providing insight into data usage across the whole of the network? I'd consider inexpensive hardware or software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you want to monitor your entire network makes things difficult, if you wanted to monitor just your computers there are a number of free programs (I use Networx), but to add wifi enable devices to the equation makes things more complicated.

First have you checked to see if your router already has monitoring software installed? If it does use that, it will be far simpler and more accurate then other methods. If it doesn't have pre-installed software look into PRTG and SparrowIQ they might do what you want they aren't cheap but they offer a free version (PRTG) or trial (sparrow)

[SparrowIQ](http://www.sparrowiq.com/)

[PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/router_bandwidth_monitor)

A method for a more advanced user would be to install a third-party firmware with bandwidth monitoring onto your router, but it voids the warranty and runs the risk of bricking it.

Comment: When you say third-party firmware, which do you mean? DD-WRT or something else? I'm not adverse to installing custom firmware.

Comment: Yeah DD-WRT or similar. It's been some time since I looked into things so I can't really give any recommendations.